# MongoDB: using long text as _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

**background & needs** 
I have documents in MongoDB with a natural primary key of type text (an url or a sentence, let's call it `text`). I need to ensure uniqueness. I also often use partial searches (`text` *contains* `substring`), but this part is less critical.

With MongoDB < 4.2, the index key limit is 1024 bytes, forcing me to use a hash as `_id`. However, version 4.2 removes the Index Key Limit ([doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)).

**question** using version 4.2, what would be better:

1. use `text` as the `_id` or
2. use a hashed id (`_id: hex_md5(text)`) and add an *index* on the `text` field (potentially a *text index* to speed up the partial searches);

To reformulate, I wonder what are the downsides of having a long text as an `_id`. Is the index created different from another "regular" index ? Do I gain anything by using md5 ids ?